# How do I get ConTeXt to produce pdf files in one directory, the aux files in a second, and take the .tex files from a third?

Tags: context

I want to be able to cleanly use my letterhead template with many different input files.

I have created a shell scrip that invokes:

`context --silent --purgeall --path=./img content/$1`

But have found no arguments that could replace the less than optimal purgeall (as I don't actually want to purge them, I just don't want to see them). Are there any?

Comment: If 2nd==3rd, use `--result=....`.

Comment: 2nd==3rd separation most important. Or some answer indicating that "you're doing it wrong. If you just organize your files like such and such, you'll be fine."

Comment: AFAIK, context does not provide such a feature. One option will be to put your letterhead template in TEXMFHOME so that it is found from all locations, or you could keep the template files in the parent or grandparent directory. Of course, even in these cases, context will generate PDF and tuc file in the same directory and you'll have to move them manually.

Comment: Moving files around and doing the compilation in a temporary directory (or dot files in the current directory, as Emacs does with compiling regions) is a possibility.  It sounds like more work than is worthwhile.  Aditya's solution is good: note also that Context recognises the TEXMFLOCAL environment variable.

Comment: @Aditya Could you make your comment here into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `context` script does not provide a way to specify the directory for output and auxiliary files.

One option is to use `--result` option, i.e.,

```
context --result=pdfs/output.pdf input.tex
```

which will move the `.pdf` **and** the `.tuc` and `.log` files to the `pdfs/` directory.

For images and tex file, you can specify you can either use the `--path` switch as you are doing right now, or specify the path in the main tex file using `\usepath` and `\setupexternalfigures[directory=...]`.